# Why is this if statement returning false every time?

Tags: php, if-statement

I have a piece of code. It is returning false every time, despite the fact that condition is true. Where am I wrong?

```
$a = 5;
$b = 10;
$c = 15;

if( ($c > $b) > $a){
    echo "yes";
} else {
    echo "no";
}
```

Comment: `($c > $b)` return true and `true>$a` that's false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your data

`($c > $b)` is `true`.

`true > $a` is `false`.

```
var_dump(100 < TRUE); // FALSE - same as (bool)100 < TRUE
var_dump(-10 < FALSE);// FALSE - same as (bool)-10 < FALSE
```

[Comparison Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Should be -

```
if( ($c > $b) && ($c> $a)) {
```

Answer (score 2):

`($c > $b)` returns true. Then you get `true > $a` which would be false.

You should either nest the *if* statement or think of something like:

```
if( $c > $b &&  $c > $a){
```

Answer (score 1):

`($c > $b)` yields true, **represented by a 1 in numeric expressions**.

`1 > $a` is definitively false.

Probably `($c>$b && $b>a)` is what you are looking for, if you want be $b in the range between $c and $a.

Answer (score 1):

The expression can be explained as:

```
1. true = 15 > 10
2. 1    = (int) true
3. true = 5 > 1
```

`($l > $m)` is converted to an integer representation of `true`, which is `1` and `1` is less than `5`